# Using Firedac For MongoDB's Time Range Query

Tags: c++, mongodb, firedac, c++builder-10-seattle

I has one question about time range query.

Here is my code:

```
TMongoPipeline*  MGPipeline = new TMongoPipeline(FEnv);
MGPipeline->Match()->Doc->AsJSON="{DayTime:{$gt:ISODate(\"2000-11-02T17:04:11.102Z\")}}";                           ^^^^^^^^^
```

where `DayTime` field's Data type is **Date**

Compile is ok, but it always throw an exception as like this:

> project TestC.cpp raised exception class EJSONReaderException with message 'Cannot read Infinity value' Path 'DayTime', line 1, position 9'.

I also tried another code:

```
TMongoPipeline*  MGPipeline = new TMongoPipeline(FEnv);
MGPipeline->Match()->Doc->AsJSON="{DayTime:{$gt:new Date(2001,1,1)}}";
                                                ^^^^^^^^^
```

But it throw exception,too.

> TestC.cpp raised exception class $C0000094 with message 'integer divide by zero at 0x50096'

My MongoDB version is 3.0.

Now I can't do any time range query.

Can tell me anyway to do that by using FireDac and Rad Studio XE10?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/):

```
MGPipeline->Match()->Doc->AsJSON="{DayTime:{$gt:{\"$date\":\"2000-11-02T17:04:11.102Z\"}}}";
```